# Бот aiogram отвечает в группу, а не в личные сообщения

Tags: python, telegram, aiogram

Есть группа где бот админ, есть опрос пользователя по команде боту.
Проблема в том, если с группы ввести команду, бот начинает опрос в личных сообщениях, но ответы ждет из группы. В итоге отвечаешь в группе а вопросы от бота прилетают в личку и группа захломляется. Подскажите как его заставить в личке ответы принимать

```
@dp.message_handler(commands=['add'])
async def cmd_reg(message: types.Message) -> None:
    await bot.send_message(message.from_user.id,"Введите название улицы", reply_markup=get_cancel_kb())
    await message.delete()
    await ProjectStatesGroup.street.set()
    

@dp.message_handler(state=ProjectStatesGroup.street)
async def load_street(message: types.Message, state: FSMContext) -> None:
    async with state.proxy() as data:
        data['street'] = message.text
    
    await message.reply("Введите номер дома")
    await ProjectStatesGroup.next()


@dp.message_handler(state=ProjectStatesGroup.numb)
async def load_numb(message: types.Message, state: FSMContext) -> None:
    async with state.proxy() as data:
        data['numb'] = message.text
    
    await message.reply("Введите краткое описание обьекта")
    await ProjectStatesGroup.next()

@dp.message_handler(state=ProjectStatesGroup.desc)
async def load_desc(message: types.Message, state: FSMContext) -> None:
    async with state.proxy() as data:
        data['desc'] = message.text
    
    await message.reply("Загрузите файл")
    await ProjectStatesGroup.next()

@dp.message_handler(state=ProjectStatesGroup.url, content_types=['document'])
async def get_file(message: types.File, state: FSMContext):
    file_id = message.document.file_id
    file = await bot.get_file(file_id)
    file_path = file.file_path 
    name = message.document.file_name
    await bot.download_file_by_id(file_id, f"Uploads/{name}")

    async with state.proxy() as data:
        data['url'] = file_path
    
    await create_project(state, user_id=message.from_user.id)
    await message.reply("Объект успешно добавлен!")
    await state.finish()
```

Comment: `await bot.send_message(message.from_user.id, "text")`

Comment: Юзер пишет в группе \add  ему приходит личное сообщение от бота Введите улицу, юзер в личных сообщениях боту отвечает, но ничего не происходит пока юзер не вернется в группу и напишет там

Comment: Само собой вы же стейт указываете в текущем чате, а не в лс...

Comment: Задавай стейт так `await state.storage.set_state(chat=message.from_user.id, user=message.from_user.id, state=ProjectStatesGroup.street.state)`

Comment: Спасибо огромное, только не state.storage.set_state, а при dp = Dispatcher(bot, storage=storage) будет dp.storage.set_state. Можете добавить в ответ

Comment: Можно и state просто добавить аргумент в текущую функцию